# Move images on JPanel in Java

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to place some images on a JPanel and make them "relocatable" so I can click on one of the images and move to somewhere else on the JPanel while holding the button. It works fine with one image but I just can't come up with a solution for more images than one. I have checked many examples and tried many different ways. If you have any idea please share with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works fine with one image but I just can't come up with a solution for more images than one.

You can use the [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/). You register the component with the class and then you can move any component.

Or if you don't need the full features of the `ComponentMover` class you can just use the basic listener for dragging a component.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day! This code is brilliant. :)

Comment: This is great! Glad I stumbled upon this question. Thanks!